# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes sometimes suddenly

Tags: freeze

I have a Ubuntu system and it freezes suddenly/randomly whenever I do something from the terminal.

The last two instances it happened was when I deleted a directory and when I created a Virtual environment.

The screen doesn't freezes as such. For eg the mouse is active but all the icons are not responsive.

My specs are
Intel Core i5 8th gen
8GB RAM
Nvidia MX250

It started happening from yesterday after I upgraded the Ubuntu base.

Comment: On the grub, when you selected "advance boot option" and boot on the previous kernel, do you still experimenting freezes ? I had my computer freezing for a while, it ended with a major kernel update. If it stops, mind making a Ubuntu bug report

Comment: @B.duGaray , I have not tried that. But I got my kernel upgraded to the latest one today and have not experienced any freezes from then. Lets see if it happens again